# What Groovy version is provided by Spring Boot?

Tags: maven, groovy, spring-boot

I am working on creating a Spring Boot (1.0.2.RELEASE) application that is built with Maven 3. I created my controller class as `MyController.groovy` and was able to build it and run it with `mvn clean package && java -jar target/myApp.jar`. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 as my IDE and it fails to compile the Groovy classes because I haven't explicity declared a Groovy library to use to compile?

How can I find out which version of Groovy is provided implicitly by Spring Boot, so that I can add it in my IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Groovy 2.2.1 used in Spring Boot 1.0.2.RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L54).